# how to disable breadcrumbs under main toolbar

Tags: intellij-idea

in intellij idea community version there is no option to disable breadcrumbs in view/appearance (where it used to be), breadcrumbs itself cannot be rightclicked, in settings editor->general->breadcrumbs is disabled.

Please, where can this be disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View -> Appearance -> Navigation Bar` should get rid of it. Unless it's not there in the community version.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I tried everything in appearence menu, but I clearly missed this.

Comment: it removes whole NavigationBar, means also debug, git, ... which are pretty useful. What about remove only breadcrumb from NavigationBar, is it possible?

Comment: I found it, it is contained on Toolbar as well. So disable <View -> Appearance -> Navigation Bar> and enable <View -> Appearance -> Toolbar>

Answer (score 0):

It is under Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | [**Breadcrumbs**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-breadcrumbs.html):

[image]

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, but in question is said, that this is already disabled, and breadcrumbs are still visible